# Conversion Uppercase in .liquid

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

I want to put a capital letter at the beginning of each word in the variable {{ article.author }} thanks to the script at the bottom of the page which works because I am fetching the variable with capital letters in the console.

[image]

But I don't poorly understand the variable is displayed in uppercase on the site.

[image: Name of author in uppercase]

For CSS : [image]

Do you have an idea ?

```
{%- if article and article != empty -%}
  {%- liquid
    assign ratio = 1
    if media_aspect_ratio != nil
      assign ratio = media_aspect_ratio
    endif
  -%}
  <div class="card-wrapper underline-links-hover">
    {% comment %} <article aria-labelledby="Article-{{ article.id }}"> {% endcomment %}
    <div class="card article-card
      card--{{ settings.card_style }}
      {% if media_height and media_height != 'adapt' %} article-card__image--{{ media_height }}{% endif %}
      {% if article.image and show_image %} card--media{% else %} card--text{% endif %}
      {% if settings.card_style == 'card' %} color-{{ settings.card_color_scheme }} gradient{% endif %}
      {% if settings.card_style == 'card' and media_height == nil and article.image == empty or show_image == false %} ratio{% endif %}"
      style="--ratio-percent: {{ 1 | divided_by: ratio | times: 100 }}%;"
    >
      <div class="card__inner {% if settings.card_style == 'standard' %} color-{{ settings.card_color_scheme }} gradient{% endif %}{% if article.image and show_image or settings.card_style == 'standard' %} ratio{% endif %}" style="--ratio-percent: {{ 1 | divided_by: ratio | times: 100 }}%;">
        {%- if show_image == true and article.image -%}
          <div class="article-card__image-wrapper card__media">
            <div class="article-card__image media media--hover-effect" {% if section.settings.media_height == 'adapt' %} style="padding-bottom: {{ 1 | divided_by: article.image.aspect_ratio | times: 100 }}%;"{% endif %}>
              {% comment %}theme-check-disable ImgLazyLoading{% endcomment %}
              <img
                srcset="{%- if article.image.src.width >= 165 -%}{{ article.image.src | image_url: width: 165 }} 165w,{%- endif -%}
                  {%- if article.image.src.width >= 360 -%}{{ article.image.src | image_url: width: 360 }} 360w,{%- endif -%}
                  {%- if article.image.src.width >= 533 -%}{{ article.image.src | image_url: width: 533 }} 533w,{%- endif -%}
                  {%- if article.image.src.width >= 720 -%}{{ article.image.src | image_url: width: 720 }} 720w,{%- endif -%}
                  {%- if article.image.src.width >= 1000 -%}{{ article.image.src | image_url: width: 1000 }} 1000w,{%- endif -%}
                  {%- if article.image.src.width >= 1500 -%}{{ article.image.src | image_url: width: 1500 }} 1500w,{%- endif -%}
                  {{ article.image.src | image_url }} {{ article.image.src.width }}w"
                src="{{ article.image.src | image_url: width: 533 }}"
                sizes="(min-width: {{ settings.page_width }}px) {{ settings.page_width | minus: 100 | divided_by: 2 }}px, (min-width: 750px) calc((100vw - 130px) / 2), calc((100vw - 50px) / 2)"
                alt="{{ article.image.src.alt | escape }}"
                class="motion-reduce"
                {% unless lazy_load == false %}loading="lazy"{% endunless %}
                width="{{ article.image.width }}"
                height="{{ article.image.height }}"
              >
              {% comment %}theme-check-enable ImgLazyLoading{% endcomment %}
            </div>
          </div>
        {%- endif -%}
        <div class="card__content">        
          <div class="card__information">
            <h3 class="card__heading{% if show_excerpt %} h2{% endif %}">
              <a href="{{ article.url }}" class="full-unstyled-link">
                {{ article.title | truncate: 50 | escape }}
              </a>
            </h3>
            <div class="article-card__info caption-with-letter-spacing h5">
              {%- if show_date -%}
                <span class="circle-divider">{{ article.published_at | time_tag: '%d/%m/%Y' }}</span>
              {%- endif -%}
              {%- if show_author -%}
                <span id="blog_author">{{ article.author }}</span>
              {%- endif -%}
            </div>
            {%- if show_excerpt -%}
              {%- if article.excerpt.size > 0 or article.content.size > 0 -%}
                <p class="article-card__excerpt rte-width">
                  {%- if article.excerpt.size > 0 -%}
                    {{ article.excerpt | strip_html | truncatewords: 30 }}
                  {%- else -%}
                    {{ article.content | strip_html | truncatewords: 30 }}
                  {%- endif -%}
                </p>
              {%- endif -%}
              <div class="article-card__footer">
                {%- if article.comments_count > 0 and blog.comments_enabled? -%}
                  <span>{{ 'blogs.article.comments' | t: count: article.comments_count }}</span>
                {%- endif -%}
              </div>
            {%- endif -%}
          </div>
          {%- if show_badge -%}
            <div class="card__badge {{ settings.badge_position }}">
              <span class="badge color-background-1">{{ 'blogs.article.blog' | t }}</span>
            </div>
          {%- endif -%}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card__content">
        <div class="card__information">
          <h3 class="card__heading{% if show_excerpt %} h2{% endif %}">
            <a href="{{ article.url }}" class="full-unstyled-link">
              {{ article.title | truncate: 50 | escape }}
            </a>
          </h3>
          <div class="article-card__info caption-with-letter-spacing h5">
            {%- if show_date -%}
              <span class="circle-divider">{{ article.published_at | time_tag: '%d/%m/%Y' }}</span>
            {%- endif -%}
            {%- if show_author -%}
              <span id="blog_author">{{ article.author }}</span>
            {%- endif -%}
          </div>
          {%- if show_excerpt -%}
            {%- if article.excerpt.size > 0 or article.content.size > 0 -%}
              <p class="article-card__excerpt rte-width">
                {%- if article.excerpt.size > 0 -%}
                  {{ article.excerpt | strip_html | truncatewords: 30 }}
                {%- else -%}
                  {{ article.content | strip_html | truncatewords: 30 }}
                {%- endif -%}
              </p>
            {%- endif -%}
            <div class="article-card__footer">
              {%- if article.comments_count > 0 and blog.comments_enabled? -%}
                <span>{{ 'blogs.article.comments' | t: count: article.comments_count }}</span>
              {%- endif -%}
            </div>
          {%- endif -%}
        </div>
        {%- if show_badge -%}
          <div class="card__badge {{ settings.badge_position }}">
            <span class="badge color-background-1">{{ 'blogs.article.blog' | t }}</span>
          </div>
        {%- endif -%}  
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
{%- endif -%}


<script>
    const elmBlogAuthor = document.getElementById("blog_author");
    const oldName = elmBlogAuthor.innerText;
    const newName = oldName.toLowerCase().replace(/\b\w/g, chr => chr.toUpperCase());
    elmBlogAuthor.innerText = newName; // update the element contents

    console.log(oldName, "->", newName);
</script>
```

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand well, author var is encoded with caps in Liquid data source.

I'd say something like that should work (not tested):

```
{% liquid
    assign author = article.author | downcase
    assign author_parts = author | split:' '
    for part in author_parts
        echo part | capitalize | append: ' '
    endfor
%}
```

Comment: It seems to work but how can I display the result ? Because "echo" display in console

Comment: @Sally You do not need JS, you may simply replace {{ article.author }} in your Liquid code by this snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You never update the actual element contents:

> ```html
> <script>
> var span = document.getElementById("blog_author").innerText.toLowerCase().replace(/\b(\w)/g, x => x.toUpperCase());
>   console.log(span);
> </script>
> ```

The code above takes the contents of `#blog_author`. The text (not the element) is then modified and stored in the `span` variable, but the text contents of `#blog_author` is never updated.

To solve this issue you should reassign the text to the element.

```html
<script>
const elmBlogAuthor = document.getElementById("blogAuthor");
const oldName = elmBlogAuthor.innerText;
const newName = oldName.toLowerCase().replace(/\b\w/g, chr => chr.toUpperCase());
elmBlogAuthor.innerText = newName; // update the element contents

console.log(oldName, "->", newName);
</script>
```

Comment: Yes but it still doesn't work, in the console it's good! On the other hand, the rendering on the site is always in full capitals...

Comment: @Sally Do you have any CSS that forces text to be displayed in full uppercase? eg. [`text-transform: uppercase;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform)

Comment: No, none.. zero CSS that forces

Comment: @Sally Are you sure? How have you checked? Did you go into the browser developer tools (`Ctrl + I`), select the relevant element, and checked the calculated properties? See [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMIrf.png) You might not have any CSS, but it could come from a 3rd party theme/template you're using.

Comment: New image in post for CSS.  And the information, the format of {{ article.author }} in Shopify API is "FREDERIC MARREC" in uppercase.